# A tibble: 0 x 0 output while combining two csv files in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning, tibble

R Studio 4.0.2
Packages:
ggplot2 3.3.2  , purrr   0.3.4
tibble  3.0.4   dplyr   1.0.2
tidyr   1.1.2   stringr 1.4.0
readr   1.4.0   forcats 0.5.0

I am trying to combine two CSV files and getting A tibble 0 x 0 output. One of these files has 2070 rows and 21 cols, other file has 2014 rows and 33 cols. When I used the code below, regardless of the function, I have this output: A tibble: 0 x 0 output
Schools_safety1517 supposed to be the combination of the two CSV files(ss1516 & ss1517). These data have Infos about the maintenance of crime data for incidents that occur in New York City public schools. ss1516 & ss1617 have Infos like school address, school name, and school id in the systems. I am trying to combine these two CSV data and create new CSV data by using the code below. as an expected output, I am expecting a new CSV file that has values in these two CSV files(There is 43.491 value in ss1516 CSV file and 66.462 value in ss1617 CSV file. But when I implement this code, I have this output: A tibble: 0 x 0 output and 0 value.
How could I solve this and combine these two CSV files?

```
> school_safety1517 <- list.files(pattern = "ss1_.*csv")
> df_list <- lapply(school_safety1517,read_csv)
> df <- bind_rows(df_list)
> head(df)
# A tibble: 0 x 0
> df <- bind_cols(df_list)
> df
# A tibble: 0 x 0
> ss_1516 <- ss1516
> ss_1617 <- ss1617
> files <- list.files(pattern = "file_.csv")
> files <- list.files(pattern = "ss_1.*csv")
> df_list <- lapply(files,read_csv)
> df <- bind_rows(df_list)
> head(df)
# A tibble: 0 x 0
> df
# A tibble: 0 x 0
```

Edit :
Here is the summary Infos about the data I'm working on:
First 6 rows of ss1516:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 24
     ID `Building Code` DBN   `Location Name` `Location Code` Address Borough
  <dbl> <chr>           <chr> <chr>           <chr>           <chr>   <chr>  
1     1 K001            15K0~ P.S. 001 The B~ K001            309 47~ K      
2     2 K002            17K0~ Parkside Prepa~ K002            655 PA~ K      
3     3 K002            84K7~ EXPLORE CHARTE~ K704            655 PA~ K      
4     4 K002            75K1~ P.S. K141       K141            655 PA~ K      
5     5 K002            NA    655 PARKSIDE A~ NA              655 PA~ K      
6     6 K003            13K0~ P.S. 003 The B~ K003            50 JEF~ K      
# ... with 17 more variables: `Geographical District Code` <dbl>,
#   Register <chr>, `Building Name` <chr>, `# Schools` <dbl>, `Schools in
#   Building` <chr>, `Major N` <chr>, `Oth N` <chr>, `NoCrim N` <chr>, `Prop
#   N` <chr>, `Vio N` <chr>, ENGroupA <chr>, RangeA <chr>, `AvgOfMajor
#   N` <chr>, `AvgOfOth N` <chr>, `AvgOfNoCrim N` <chr>, `AvgOfProp N` <chr>,
#   `AvgOfVio N` <chr>
```

First 6 rows of ss1617:

```
> head(ss1617)
  School.Year                                      Location.Name Location.Code Borough
1   2016 - 17                    PASSAGES ACADEMY AT BELMONT(BN)          X695       K
2   2016 - 17                                          P.S. Q086          Q086       Q
3   2016 - 17                                P.S. 001 The Bergen          K001       K
4   2016 - 17                           P.S. 001 Alfred E. Smith          M001       M
5   2016 - 17                                           P.S. 035          M035       M
6   2016 - 17 The Urban Assembly School for Collaborative Health          K764       K
  Geographical.District.Code Register                            Building.Name X..Schools
1                          7      618                                                   1
2                         28      646                                                   1
3                         15     1334                                                   1
4                          2      533                                                   1
5                          2      833                                                   1
6                         19      215 999 JAMAICA AVENUE CONSOLIDATED LOCATION          5
  NYPD.Site.Code      NYPD.Site.Name
1            211             PS 077K
2            746             MS 074Q
3            198             PS 001K
4           1398      Sunset Park HS
5            663            JHS 056M
6            315 SAMUEL J. TILDEN HS
                                                                                                                                                                                                          Schools.in.Building
1                                                                                                                                                                                                    Brooklyn College Academy
2                                                                                                                                                                                                            P.S. 082 Hammond
3                                                                                                                                                                                                         P.S. 001 The Bergen
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                   P.S. Q256
5                                                                                                                                                                                                        James Weldon Johnson
6 Multicultural High School |Academy of Innovative Technology |Brooklyn Lab School |Cypress Hills Collegiate Preparatory School |The Urban Assembly School for Collaborative Health |999 JAMAICA AVENUE CONSOLIDATED LOCATION
  Major.N Oth.N NoCrim.N Prop.N Vio.N ENGroupA    RangeA AvgOfMajor.N AvgOfOth.N AvgOfNoCrim.N
1       0     0        1      0     0       4C   501-750         0.28       1.11          1.74
2       0     1        0      1     0       4C   501-750         0.28       1.11          1.74
3       0     0        1      0     0       7C 1251-1500         0.64       3.02          5.77
4       0     1        0      0     1       4C   501-750         0.28       1.11          1.74
5       0     1        3      0     1       5C  751-1000         0.38       1.71          2.38
6     N/A   N/A      N/A    N/A   N/A       2C     1-250          N/A        N/A           N/A
  AvgOfProp.N AvgOfVio.N                                         Geocode Postcode Latitude
1        0.75       0.53       560 BROOK AVENUE\n(40.815701, -73.914526)       NA       NA
2        0.75       0.53 87 41 PARSONS BOULEVARD\n(41.12133, -72.339742)    11432 40.70890
3        1.72       1.54          309 47 STREET\n(41.574857, -93.767342)       NA       NA
4        0.75       0.53         8 HENRY STREET\n(41.398617, -73.465855)       NA       NA
5        0.98       0.82   317 WEST 52ND STREET\n(41.799996, -87.633867)    10019 40.76387
6         N/A        N/A     999 JAMAICA AVENUE\n(27.783609, -80.501816)    11208 40.69115
  Longitude Community.Board Council.District Census.Tract     BIN        BBL
1        NA              NA               NA           NA      NA         NA
2 -73.80394               8               24          448 4438678 4097740001
3        NA              NA               NA           NA      NA         NA
4        NA              NA               NA           NA      NA         NA
5 -73.98594               4                3          133 1025241 1010430022
6 -73.86833               5               37         1180 3090738 3040940001
                                                                          NTA
1                                                                            
2 Briarwood-Jamaica Hills                                                    
3                                                                            
4                                                                            
5 Clinton                                                                    
6 park-cemetery-etc-Brooklyn
```

Summary of ss1516:

```
> summary(ss1516)
       ID       Building Code          DBN            Location Name     
 Min.   :   1   Length:2070        Length:2070        Length:2070       
 1st Qu.: 518   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Median :1035   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :1035                                                           
 3rd Qu.:1552                                                           
 Max.   :2069                                                           
 NA's   :1                                                              
 Location Code        Address            Borough         
 Length:2070        Length:2070        Length:2070       
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                         
                                                         
                                                         
                                                         
 Geographical District Code   Register         Building Name     
 Min.   : 0.00              Length:2070        Length:2070       
 1st Qu.: 8.00              Class :character   Class :character  
 Median :14.00              Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :15.37                                                   
 3rd Qu.:23.00                                                   
 Max.   :32.00                                                   
 NA's   :4                                                       
   # Schools     Schools in Building   Major N             Oth N          
 Min.   :1.000   Length:2070         Length:2070        Length:2070       
 1st Qu.:1.000   Class :character    Class :character   Class :character  
 Median :2.000   Mode  :character    Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :2.211                                                            
 3rd Qu.:3.000                                                            
 Max.   :8.000                                                            
 NA's   :1                                                                
   NoCrim N            Prop N             Vio N             ENGroupA        
 Length:2070        Length:2070        Length:2070        Length:2070       
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                                                            
    RangeA          AvgOfMajor N        AvgOfOth N        AvgOfNoCrim N     
 Length:2070        Length:2070        Length:2070        Length:2070       
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                                                            
 AvgOfProp N         AvgOfVio N       
 Length:2070        Length:2070       
 Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character
```

Summary of ss1617:

```
> summary(ss1617)
 School.Year        Location.Name      Location.Code        Borough         
 Length:2046        Length:2046        Length:2046        Length:2046       
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                                                            
 Geographical.District.Code   Register         Building.Name        X..Schools   NYPD.Site.Code    
 Min.   : 0.00              Length:2046        Length:2046        Min.   :1.00   Length:2046       
 1st Qu.: 8.00              Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:1.00   Class :character  
 Median :14.00              Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :2.00   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :15.46                                                    Mean   :2.13                     
 3rd Qu.:24.00                                                    3rd Qu.:3.00                     
 Max.   :32.00                                                    Max.   :8.00                     
                                                                                                   
 NYPD.Site.Name     Schools.in.Building   Major.N             Oth.N             NoCrim.N        
 Length:2046        Length:2046         Length:2046        Length:2046        Length:2046       
 Class :character   Class :character    Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character    Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
    Prop.N             Vio.N             ENGroupA            RangeA          AvgOfMajor.N      
 Length:2046        Length:2046        Length:2046        Length:2046        Length:2046       
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
  AvgOfOth.N        AvgOfNoCrim.N      AvgOfProp.N         AvgOfVio.N          Geocode         
 Length:2046        Length:2046        Length:2046        Length:2046        Length:2046       
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
    Postcode        Latitude       Longitude      Community.Board  Council.District
 Min.   :10001   Min.   :40.51   Min.   :-74.24   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   : 1.00   
 1st Qu.:10451   1st Qu.:40.67   1st Qu.:-73.96   1st Qu.: 3.000   1st Qu.:12.00   
 Median :11102   Median :40.73   Median :-73.92   Median : 7.000   Median :23.00   
 Mean   :10788   Mean   :40.74   Mean   :-73.92   Mean   : 7.306   Mean   :24.31   
 3rd Qu.:11226   3rd Qu.:40.82   3rd Qu.:-73.88   3rd Qu.:11.000   3rd Qu.:37.00   
 Max.   :11694   Max.   :40.90   Max.   :-73.71   Max.   :18.000   Max.   :51.00   
 NA's   :26      NA's   :26      NA's   :26       NA's   :26       NA's   :26      
  Census.Tract           BIN               BBL                NTA           
 Min.   :     1.0   Min.   :1000003   Min.   :1.000e+09   Length:2046       
 1st Qu.:   155.0   1st Qu.:2005348   1st Qu.:2.027e+09   Class :character  
 Median :   312.5   Median :3042210   Median :3.014e+09   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :  7065.4   Mean   :2743071   Mean   :2.674e+09                     
 3rd Qu.:   896.0   3rd Qu.:3394175   3rd Qu.:3.082e+09                     
 Max.   :157903.0   Max.   :5158758   Max.   :5.079e+09                     
 NA's   :26         NA's   :30        NA's   :30
```

Links for import the datasets:
ss1516: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/44t3-dj6x/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
ss1617: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/rear-wh5i/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD

Comment: What does `school_safety1517` consist of?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. It's impossible to know why you have an empty data frame without being able to see or work with any of your data

Comment: Hello @Phil,
these data have Infos about the maintenance of crime data for incidents that occur in New York City public schools. ss1516 & ss1617 have Infos like school address, school name, and school id in the systems. 
If you want to take a look at the data, imported these data from the following addresses:
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/rear-wh5i/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/44t3-dj6x/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD

Comment: Hello @camille. Thank you for your response, I tried to edit my question according to the instructions.

Comment: `school_safety1517` wouldn't have data, but a vector of file names. This is why I'm asking for what they consist of, because it's likely not properly allowing for `read_csv()` to read in the files.

Comment: What happens when you run `now(df_list[[1]])` from the R console after running `lapply()` as listed in your post? BTW, when I download the data files and read them with your `lapply()` code, `bind_rows()` works as expected, creating a data frame with 4116 rows.

Comment: Just figured out, I wrote the code right, but instead of going on with the `df `, I went with `school_safety1517` Which is meaningless because the final version of my combination is `df`; not `school_safety1517` It is very hard to code when you have ADHD...
Thank you all for your answers and efforts @Phil @Len Greski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last version of my dataframe is `df`  , not `school_safety1517` That's why trying to find  `schoolsafety1517` 's output is meaningless.